# How to get AR.Drone 2 Video with UDP Network

Tags: ar.drone

Does somebody already try to get the video stream of the Parrot AR Drone with UDP network ?
We already bricked 2 Drone by trying change their sofware ! :D

Comment: I think one of the big changes between version 1 and version 2 of the AR.Drone is that video is now sent over TCP instead of UDP.  Why do you need UDP?

Comment: It is for Real Time Video, because of TCP, I get deleayed Image and I don't need to get all my frames :)